# email forward to email-to-case

Tags: email2case

I have a situation in which an agent is getting work emails to his private inbox and he would like to forward them on behalf of the customer to salesforce and to create new case. The problem is that if the agent is forwarding the case to the support inbox which has a redirect rule to salesforce email2case address the new created case web address is the agent and not the original mail sender (the customer). This causing afterward an issue to set the contact on the case.
Any idea how we can get the original sender to show on the case and not the agent who did the forwarding on his behalf?
Same situation works perfect on desk.com

Comment: Post the header of one of these emails. I'm pretty sure the original sender is lost once the envelope gets a new sender address during the forward vs a redirect which keeps headers in tact.

Comment: of course, one could ask -- why is the agent getting work emails from customers to a non-work email address?  Maybe the agent should auto-reply the messages back to the customer asking them to be sent to the proper support address.

Comment: I would think there would be a number of ways you could *potentially* do this if the agent either cc'd the original contact or put their email address in the subject line. But, since I don't regularly work with email to case, I can't give you a specific solution that I know would work. Obviously, he's trying to service his client which makes perfect sense to me and your processes should be designed to accommodate that in some manner to avoid further inconveniencing your customer.

Comment: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663316-Passing-an-email-to-your-support-address other tools offer this functionality, such as FreshDesk or ZenDesk! would really be an important feature for Salesforce as well!